# Why does total Loss of Object detection looks very bad?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

[image]**Describe the problem:**

I run the object_detection train.py script, which is running successfully.  But Total loss is pretty huge. I will attach the screenshot. Please let me know, if this behaviour is due to new changes done in repository ? Because i'm pretty sure that i have followed all the instructions perfectly.

System information

What is the top-level directory of the model you are using: ~/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection

Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): No custom code, and using a neural network supplied in the object_detection folders. The dataset for retraining is my own.

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux Ubuntu 16.04

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Source

TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.4.0-rc0

Bazel version (if compiling from source):

Python version 2.7

CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA 8.0, cudnn 6.0, nVidia driver: 384.90

GPU: nVidia TitanXp 12GB memory

Exact command to reproduce:
python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path="/home/ubuntu/new-mask-branch/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config" --train_dir="/home/ubuntu/new-mask-branch/models/research/object_detection/output/atrous_mask"

Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss/mul_1 -- this loss contribution more(99% of loss is getting higher because of this)

Note: I'm getting kind of loss, after taking the latest check-in.

Comment: Just to check, this same command line, same config was working before?

Comment: Yes. It was working fine. After the new code checki-in i'm facing this issue

Comment: @coders Are you able to checkout https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/edcd29f2dbb4b3eaed387fe17cb5270f867aec42 and verify that you don't see this issue? Thanks

Comment: @tombstone u mean to say, get the code base of this commit#2590 and start the training?